# Xml - Inject result of method in a bean property

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, javabeans, blueprint-osgi

I'm using Apache Camel and i have a bean tag in the blueprint.xml file as shown below:

```
 <bean id="shiroPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.component.shiro.security.ShiroSecurityPolicy">
          <argument value="shiro.ini"/>
               <property name="permissionsList" >
             <list>
                .......
            </list> 
          </property>
       </bean>
```

The permissionsList property is a result of method perm() on this class:

```
public class testshiro{

    public List<Permission> perm()
    {
        List<Permission> permissionsList = new ArrayList<Permission>();
        Permission permission = new WildcardPermission("zone");
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        return permissionsList;
    }
    ....
```

How can i call this method and set the result in permissionsList property on the bean tag ?

Comment: You can create a OSGI-service that will give you a list of permissions. It's not too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="permissionsFactory" class="com.ngt.shiropermission.testshiro"/>
<bean id="permissions" factory-ref="permissionsFactory" factory-method="perm" />
<bean id="shiroPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.component.shiro.security.ShiroSecurityPolicy">
    <argument value="shiro.ini"/>
    <property  name="permissionsList" ref="permissions" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to instantiate `testshiro` as a factory and then speficy `perm()` as a factory method to create the list. Then pass the reference to the list to your Shiro policy:

```
<bean id="permissionsFactory" class="your.package.testshiro"/>

<bean id="permissions" factory-ref="permissionsFactory" factory-method="perm" />

<bean id="shiroPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.component.shiro.security.ShiroSecurityPolicy">
    <argument value="shiro.ini"/>
    <property  name="permissionsList" ref="permissions" />
</bean>
```

This [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-osgiblueprint/) gives a good overview on how to use factories in Blueprint.

Comment: i did this: 
`<bean id="permissions" class="com.ngt.shiropermission.wcard" factory-method="perm"/>

<bean id="shiroPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.component.shiro.security.ShiroSecurityPolicy">
    <argument value="shiro.ini"/>
    <property  name="permissionsList" ref="permissions" />
</bean>`

And i got this error message: `Unable to find a matching factory method perm on class com.ngt.shiropermission.wcard for arguments [] when instanciating bean permissions`

Comment: @zied123456, and perm() takes no arguments?

Comment: no arguments like this: `public List<Permission> perm()
    {
        List<Permission> permissionsList = new ArrayList<Permission>();
        Permission permission = new WildcardPermission("zone");
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        return permissionsList;
    }`

Comment: @zied123456 Sorry, I missed that your factory method is not static. I have updated my answer to reflect your case of an instance factory method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralf! it works now. i added the right answer for the post.

Comment: @zied123456, if it works, then it would be nice if you can mark my answer as correct.

Comment: i didn't marked your answer as correct beacause it dont works, you have to change `factory-ref="your.package.testshiro"` by  `factory-ref="permissionsFactory"` i changed it and added the right response bellow

Comment: @zied123456 Corrected.